# Set ko.observable value from multiple DOM elements

Tags: knockout.js

### [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/BgdaF/1/)

---

Given that I have a list of questions, with control types (i.e. text box, select list, check box etc.) in a model that is being built with `ko.mapping` from JSON retrieved via an asmx web method, how do I set the answer to a question based off multiple DOM elements?

Say I have the following question:

```
{
    text:"This is the question text",
    answer:null,
    controlType:"picker"
}
```

Then I have created a `picker` template, that looks like this:

```
<select data-bind="options: ['Large','Medium','Small'], optionsCaption: 'Select size...'" />
<select data-bind="options: ['Black','Red','Green'], optionsCaption: 'Select colour...'" />
```

I need to set the `answer` to this question when (and only when) both SELECT elements have a value selected.

I also need to persist the answer, so if the `question` comes back from the server with the answer populated (saved form submissions etc.) the respective values are selected in the SELECT elements, i.e.:

```
{
    text:"This is the question text",
    answer:"Large Red",
    controlType:"picker"
}
```

This would select [Large] and [Red] from the elements for me.

Here's what I've tried so far.

#### Setting a `ko.computed` on my observable

**EDIT**: Here's a [working jsFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/BgdaF/2/) idea.

I've looped around the questions in my view model and set a `ko.computed` on each one, that accesses the DOM via ID, so my template becomes:

```
<select data-bind="attr: { 'id':'leftOption' }, options: ['Large','Medium','Small'], optionsCaption: 'Select size...'" />
<select data-bind="attr: { 'id':'rightOption' }, options: ['Black','Red','Green'], optionsCaption: 'Select colour...'" />
```

And my computed value becomes:

```
question.computedAnswer = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return question.answer();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        var left = $('#leftOption').val();
        var right = $('#rightOption').val(); 
        question.answer(left + ' ' + right);
    }
});
```

This just screams **oh god, please, no!** at me though because I'm accessing the DOM in a very messy way (and having recently learned a good practice of not accessing the DOM like this, feels all kinds of wrong!!).

#### Creating a custom binding handler

*Caveat: I'm still getting to grips with custom handlers*

To restrict access to the DOM via a binding handler, I created one for this purpose... but can't seem to get it working. This idea is in the [provided jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/BgdaF/1/) but it's not working in that it's not doing anything!

Essentially I'm trying to do this in the handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.computedAnswer = {
    update: function (element, value, all, model, context) {
        switch (model.controlType()) {
            case 'picker': {
                var $parent = $(element).parent();
                var first = $parent.find('select:first').val();
                var second = $parent.find('select:last').val();
                if (first && second) {
                    model.answer(first + ' ' + second);
                } else {
                    model.answer(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And *trying* to activate this on my template like this:

```
<select data-bind="computedAnswer: $data, options: ['Large','Medium','Small'], optionsCaption: 'Select size...'" />
<select data-bind="computedAnswer: $data, options: ['Black','Red','Green'], optionsCaption: 'Select colour...'" />
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Your questions deserve more upvotes. You always have multiple fiddles, showing the problem and a path you think you should take, you tailor them to the specific problem you are having (even though your past questions indicate the total problem has many more parts), you include the code in your question, and clearly demonstrate effort.

Comment: @Tyrsius I appreciate that. I feel it's just common courtesy, if someone is going to take their own time out to help you - it's only fair that you should be expected to help yourself!

Comment: It's a courtesy, but certainly not common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is the wrong place to store data. It's also not very flexible. What if your `picker` questions stored their own options? That would not only allow each question to have different options, but a different *number* of options.

It also keeps data of of the view, and simplifies your HTML and viewmodel code, and keeps the DOM access out of the viewmodel without requiring a custom binding (not that you should *avoid* custom bindings at all costs, I just don't think this is a good case for them).

**A** `picker` **question**

```
}, {
    text: "dependent on master question",
    answer: null,
    controlType: "picker",
    pickers: [
        { name: "Size", options: ['Large', 'Medium', 'Small'], value: '' },
        { name: "Color", options: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'], value: '' }
    ]
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/html" id="picker">
    <!-- ko foreach: pickers -->
    <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
    <select data-bind="options: options, value: value, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

**The computed answer**

```
viewModel.questions().forEach(function (question) {
    if (question.controlType() === 'picker') {
        question.answer = ko.computed(function() {
            var answers = [];
            question.pickers().forEach(function(i) {
                if (i.value())
                    answers.push(i.value());
            });
            return answers.length === question.pickers().length ?
                answers.join(' ') : '';
        });
    }
});
```

## [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/LhNX9/2/)

Comment: Interesting, I never though about having an array of pickers along with the question... however, what if I have no control over the JSON that's coming back to me - and I have to specify the number of SELECT elements in just the template?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I could extend the observable after the JSON has been parsed with the pickers array? I think that's the way I'll go, unless I (or someone) comes up with a better way.

Comment: If you don't have control, I would extend them after they have been parsed. Because either way the viewmodel should represent the data, not the view. If the options really are static, you can just put them on the root viewmodel instead of each question.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept, doing some housekeeping on my questions.